# Getting "exports.getOrgApiVersion" When Trying to Deploy LWC to Org

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to deploy a new LWC to my personal development org for a trailhead module, but I am receiving this error in the logs when trying to deploy the component "exports.getOrgApiVersion".

The Salesforce DX Extension is up to date as well as my sfdx cli version "sfdx-cli/7.205.6 darwin-arm64 node-v16.13.1".

I have tried downgrading my sfdx cli version as well as the Salesforce DX VSCode extensions but still receive the same error.

Would anyone know how to resolve this error?

This is on an M1 Macbook Air